# Rails 4 Turbolinks and Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics

I'm looking to add Google Analytics to my Rails 4 application and have read about the issue with Turbolinks.

I have used the following answer to produce a workaround:

[Google analytics with rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632644/google-analytics-with-rails-4)

The following code is from the new analytics.js.coffee file I created under assets>javascripts

```
app/assets/javascripts/analytics.js

// Coffee
$(document).on 'page:change', ->
 if window._gaq?
  _gaq.push ['_trackPageview']
 else if window.pageTracker?
  pageTracker._trackPageview()

// Javascript
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
 if (window._gaq != null) {
  return _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
 } else if (window.pageTracker != null) {
  return pageTracker._trackPageview();
 }
});
```

Views > Layouts > _footer.html.erb (the file I setup for to load the code)

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-837283948-1', 'myapplication.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Then I placed the following code in my application.html.erb file under Views > Layouts

```
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

The render code in the application.html.erb file causes the application to crash, so I'm guessing I have done something wrong. I have followed the guide and can't get it to work.

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: Did you consider using the [google-analytics-turbolinks Gem](https://github.com/shukydvir/google-analytics-turbolinks)?

Comment: @spickermann No I was not aware of this solution. Is it similar to the above? If I'm able to make the above work with a simple change of code it would be great. Look forward to your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, it does basically the same. Have a look [at the source code](https://github.com/shukydvir/google-analytics-turbolinks/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/google-analytics-turbolinks.js.coffee)

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing you've done wrong is you're using code from two versions of Google Analytics.

In your first code sample you have the line `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);` which references the old `_gaq` global variable from the [ga.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) library.

In your second code sample you have the line `ga('send', 'pageview');` which references the new `ga` global variable from the [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) library.

Beyond that, the reason tracking pageviews with Turbolinks is hard is because Rails is converting your app from the traditional request-response
model to a single page application model.

I'd recommend reading the developer guide on [building single page apps with analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) to get an overview of how to properly do this.

...or just use the turbolinks gem if you don't want to have to learn this stuff :)