# Google Analytics and Rails 4 issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I have followed the following Stack Overflow page to produce a work around to the common issue of Turbolinks and Google Analytics not playing nicely.

[Google analytics with rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632644/google-analytics-with-rails-4)

The code is in place but Google Analytics has alerted me there is missing tracking code for the web application and no data has been captured.

**The code and setup I have used:**

Created a new file under Assets > Javascripts  (analytics.js.coffee)

```
// Coffee
    $(document).on 'page:change', ->
     if window._gaq?
      _gaq.push ['_trackPageview']
     else if window.pageTracker?
      pageTracker._trackPageview()

    // Javascript
    $(document).on('page:change', function() {
     if (window._gaq != null) {
      return _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
     } else if (window.pageTracker != null) {
      return pageTracker._trackPageview();
     }
    });
```

Create a partial in Views > Layouts (_footer.html.erb) *I use my domain and tracking ID in my application's code, just replaced for this example.*

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-55647322-1', 'www.mysite.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Added the render code to the bottom of the application layout page (application.html.erb)

```
</script>


<%= render :partial => 'layouts/footer' %>


</body>
</html>
```

Could the problem be with the Javascript file? Does it have to be a js.coffee file, or can I use simply .js?

Hopefully someone can work out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Are you able to see the analytics JS in the source code of the live page? Also, you should change www.mysite.com to reflect your actual site unless you haven't already.

Comment: @NickM thanks for  the input Nick, mysite.com is replaced with the actual domain name in the code. After taking a look, the home page does not display the _footer.html.erb partial, but the rest of the app does. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a custom template/layout for your home page? Can you post your root route and the corresponding controller?

Comment: I'm guessing the homepage does not display the partial because the render code was only added to the application.html.erb layout and not the home.html.erb layout. @NickM Do you have any ideas why it doesn't work at all though? Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it isn't working with the application layout I couldn't tell you why, but you might try including the footer render in the home layout.

Comment: A side note: in your `analytics.js.coffee` file it is suggested to chose one version of code - either javascript or coffeescript.