# Tracking with google analytics sign up page in Rails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, devise, analytics.js

I am trying to track each page of my Rails application, rendering this partial on the layout:

```
var analyticsId = '<%= Settings.env.app.analytics_id %>';

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;  i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; 
a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '<%= Settings.env.app.analytics_id %>', 'auto', 'trackEvent: true');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

After adding the Google Analytics ID to the settings, I can see in my Google Analytics dashboard the visits to my `users#sign_in` page but not the visits to my `users#sign_up` page.
Inspecting both pages through the firebug console I see the spected result in the html code:

```
var analyticsId = 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X';

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;
i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g
m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto', 'trackEvent: true');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

With 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X' = Settings.env.app.analytics_id which is defined in config/settings/app.yml under analytics_id.

We use devise to handle the signin/signup proccess and this is the part related to devise in the routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users, controllers: {
  confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
  registrations: 'users/registrations'
 }
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

 authenticated :user do
  devise_scope :user do
   root to: redirect("/home")
  end
 end

unauthenticated do
 devise_scope :user do
   root to: redirect("users/sign_in"), as: "unauthenticated_index"
   get '/pages/:page',    to: 'pages#show', as: "pages_show"
 end
end
```

Comment: Where does `Settings.env.app.analytics_id` come from? It's based on the application itself or on some logged in user? Can you elaborate a little more on how this question relates to Devise? What is the generated HTML of the snippet above?

Comment: Thanks for the advise @thiago-belem , already updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was related to the fact that:

> Rails 4.0 introduced a feature named Turbolinks to increase the
>   perceived speed of a website.
>
> Google Analytics doesn’t work for a Rails 4.0 or newer web
>   applications. To be more precise, it won’t work for all pages. It can
>   be made to work with a workaround to accommodate Turbolinks.

Making the long story short I have applied a workaround based on the answer in this post:
[Google analytics with rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632644/google-analytics-with-rails-4)