# Google analytics with Rails 5 and ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

[I've followed these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632644/google-analytics-with-rails-4) and I successfully see traffic going to my site, the problem is I can see the traffic of every controller/method **EXCEPT** those within the `admin` namespace, because the script at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` (the one shown below) is not executed at any ActiveAdmin page...

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'herokuapp.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I know Devise is able to tell me how many times an user have sign in my site, but I would like to see more statistics....

How could I solve this? I don't want put a `render partial` with that code in every ActiveAdmin's controller/method just for this task... is there an `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` equivalent for ActiveAdmin? I mean a way to put a `script` tag in every ActiveAdmin's view?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom scripts to ActiveAdmin's layout by simply editing `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`. This file should have been created when you first set up ActiveAdmin.

Create a new javascript file to hold the Google Analytics script, and simply include the new script in `active_admin.js`.

It should look something like this:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/google_analytics.js

// Google analytics script goes here.
```

```
// app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js 

//= require active_admin/base
//= require ./google_analytics
```